# Remove just the Location

Tags: objects, keyframes

Is there a way to remove just the Location section of the keyframes of an object?  I have gotten into the habit of setting LocRotScale when setting them and want to change only location. without going keyframe by keyframe because of the strange offset flight of the object.

Comment: go to the curve editor, there you can select the channels you want to delete .

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the object is selected and open a Dope Sheet window.
[image]

Each keyframe is represented by a diamond (white = Unselected, orange = Selected). You can use the usual tools to change the selection - eg, right-click to select a single keyframe, <kbd>A</kbd> for Select/Unselect All, Box Select (<kbd>B</kbd>), <kbd>Shift</kbd> for multiple select, etc. To Select all keyframes on a channel you can select one of the keyframes and then press <kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked keyframes on the same channel.

Select the keyframes you want to delete and press <kbd>X</kbd> to remove them.